# The value of the variable has been suddenly set to 0

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm doing an activity to measure how long it takes a person to do an exercise, but it has a bug that I couldn't resolve yet...

The TrainingFragment shows a list of exercises that the user can click and then my ExerciseActivity is launched and runs until the variable "remainingsSets" is setted to 0.

When I click in the first time at any exercise, everything works fine, the ExerciseActivity works correctly end return to the TrainingFragment. But then, if I try to click in another exercise, the ExerciseActivity is just closed.

In my debug, I could see that the variable "remainingSets" comes with it's right value (`remainingSets = getIntent().getIntExtra("remaining_sets", 3)`), but when the startButton is clicked, I don't know why the variable "remainingSets" is setted to 0 and then the activity is closed because this condition: `if (remainingSets > 0){...}`.

Here is my TrainingFragment:

```
public class TrainingFragment extends Fragment {

private final static int START_EXERCISE = 1;

private Training training;
private String lastItemClicked;
private String[] values;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    if (bundle != null) {
        training = bundle.getParcelable("training");
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return (ScrollView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.template_exercises, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    LinearLayout exercisesContainer = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.exercises);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    List<Exercise> exercises = training.getExercises();
    values = new String[exercises.size()];

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        values = savedInstanceState.getStringArray("values");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < exercises.size(); i++) {
        final View exerciseView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.template_exercise, null);

        exerciseView.setTag(String.valueOf(i));

        TextView remainingSets = (TextView) exerciseView.findViewById(R.id.remaining_sets);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            remainingSets.setText(values[i]);
        } else {
            String sets = exercises.get(i).getSets();
            remainingSets.setText(sets);
            values[i] = sets;
        }

        exerciseView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ExerciseActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("remaining_sets",
                        Integer.valueOf(((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.remaining_sets)).getText().toString()));

                lastItemClicked = v.getTag().toString();

                startActivityForResult(intent, START_EXERCISE);
            }
        });

        exercisesContainer.addView(exerciseView);
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putStringArray("values", values);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    View view = ((LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.exercises)).findViewWithTag(lastItemClicked);

    if (requestCode == START_EXERCISE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) { // the exercise had been
                                                // finished.
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.remaining_sets)).setText("0");

            view.setClickable(false);

            values[Integer.valueOf(lastItemClicked)] = "0";

        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {

            String remainingSets = data.getStringExtra("remaining_sets");
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.remaining_sets)).setText(remainingSets);

            values[Integer.valueOf(lastItemClicked)] = remainingSets;
        }
    }
}
}
```

My ExerciseActivity:

```
public class ExerciseActivity extends Activity {

private Chronometer chronometer;
private TextView timer;
private Button startButton;
private Button endButton;
private int remainingSets;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercise);

    ExerciseEvents.addExerciseListener(new PopupExerciseListener());

    chronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.exercise_doing_timer);
    timer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);

    startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_exercise);
    startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ExerciseEvents.onExerciseBegin();
        }
    });

    endButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.end_exercise);
    endButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ExerciseEvents.onExerciseRest();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("remaining_sets", String.valueOf(remainingSets));
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, intent);

    super.onBackPressed();
}

public class PopupExerciseListener implements ExerciseListener {

    public PopupExerciseListener() {
        remainingSets = getIntent().getIntExtra("remaining_sets", 3);
    }

    @Override
    public void onExerciseBegin() {
        if (remainingSets > 0) {
            chronometer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            timer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            chronometer.start();

            startButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            endButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            ExerciseEvents.onExerciseFinish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onExerciseFinish() {
        setResult(RESULT_OK);

        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onExerciseRest() {
        chronometer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        endButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        timer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        long restTime = getIntent().getLongExtra("time_to_rest", 60) * 1000;
        new CountDownTimer(restTime, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                timer.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                ExerciseEvents.onExerciseBegin();
            }
        }.start();

        remainingSets--;
    }
}
}
```

And my ExerciseEvents:

```
public class ExerciseEvents {

private static LinkedList<ExerciseListener> mExerciseListeners = new LinkedList<ExerciseListener>();

public static void addExerciseListener(ExerciseListener listener) {
    mExerciseListeners.add(listener);
}

public static void removeExerciseListener(String listener) {
    mExerciseListeners.remove(listener);
}

public static void onExerciseBegin() {
    for (ExerciseListener l : mExerciseListeners) {
        l.onExerciseBegin();
    }
}

public static void onExerciseRest() {
    for (ExerciseListener l : mExerciseListeners) {
        l.onExerciseRest();
    }
}

public static void onExerciseFinish() {
    for (ExerciseListener l : mExerciseListeners) {
        l.onExerciseFinish();
    }
}

public static interface ExerciseListener {

    public void onExerciseBegin();

    public void onExerciseRest();

    public void onExerciseFinish();
}
}
```

Could anyone give me any help?

Comment: Where do you read `"remaining_sets"` and where do you close your Activity? Post this code too.

Comment: You said it only happens after the 1st time.. So, your first run you do your sets and count down to 0.. your remainingSets is now at 0. You click start again.. since you don't reset remainingSets to 3, it iwll be 0 and close your app.

Comment: It's hard to figure out by just looking at the code. Put a breakpoint at each spot where 'remainingSets' is assigned or modified. That may tell you why it is set to 0 or why it reaches 0.

Comment: @dymmeh You have a point. If the ExerciseActivity has a launch mode of singleTop or singleTask, the onCreate won't be called each time (instead onNewIntent will be called) and remainingSets is 0.

Comment: @Sam, the `remaining_sets` is read from bundle object, inside of the intent (`remainingSets = getIntent().getIntExtra("remaining_sets", 3)`. The activity is closed when this test (`if (remainingSets > 0)`) fails end then the `onExerciseFinish()` is called.

Comment: @dymmeh, I think this is not the reason, because the remainingSets is setted to 0 in the ExerciseActivity, but when it return to my TraigningFragment, I update remainingSets with another value before start the ExerciseActivity again. =/

Comment: @StreetsOfBoston, my ExerciseActivity is configured to be launched with "standard" mode.

Comment: Did you set breakpoints where the value of remainingSets is changing?

Comment: @StreetsOfBoston Yes, the value of remainingSets changes to 0 when I click in startButton. Remembering that the inicial value (`remainingSets = getIntent().getIntExtra("remaining_sets", 3)`) setted at constructor is right... I really don't know what's happening... =(

Comment: You mean that this returns 0?: "Integer.valueOf(((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.remaining_sets)).getText().toString())"

Comment: No, @StreetsOfBoston. The TrainingFragment is passing the right value in the bundle. The problem is at ExerciseActivity, where the value of remainingSets suddenly changes to 0, and I don't know why...

Comment: Did you set breakpoints in your code where you change the value of remainingSets in ExcerciseActivty? I see two spots: The PopupExerciseListener constructor and in the onExerciseRest method. Put breakpoints there and see when it reaches/assigns 0 to remainingSets.

Comment: @StreetsOfBoston I've already done that, but it's value isn't changed at any of this points. The remainingSets value is right until the startButton be clicked, so when I click in it the method "onExerciseBegin()" is called and then its value just changes!

Comment: What is 'ExerciseEvents'? Where is this defined. The implementation of the class (or the class of this global variable) may cause the problem.

Comment: @StreetsOfBoston It's my class responsible for call all listeners registered. I added its code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you updated your code, I see you have a  big memory leak in your code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_exercise);

    ExerciseEvents.addExerciseListener(new PopupExerciseListener());
    ....
}
```

The call `ExerciseEvents.addExerciseListener(new PopupExerciseListener())` adds a new `PopupExerciseListener` to a static/global list: `ExcerciseEvents.mExerciseListeners`. Since the class `PopupExerciseListener` is an inner-class, it implicitly holds a reference to its enclosing `ExcerciseActivity`. This mean your code is holding on to each instance of `ExcerciseActivity` forever. Not good.

This may also explain the weird behavior you see. When one of the `onExcersizeXXX()` methods is called, it will call all ExcerciseListeners in the linked-list, the ones from previous screens and the current one.

Try this in your ExcerciseActivity.java:

```
....
ExerciseListener mExerciseListener;
....

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    ....
    mExerciseListener = new PopupExerciseListener()
    ExerciseEvents.addExerciseListener(mExerciseListener);
    ....
    ....
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    ExerciseEvents.removeExerciseListener(mExerciseListener);
    super.onDestroy();
}

....
```

In `onDestroy`, you deregister your listener, preventing a memory leak and preventing odd multiple callbacks to PopupExerciseListeners that are attached to activities that no longer exist.